# Cakephp JsHelper and SVG

Tags: cakephp, svg

Is it possible to bind in cakephp an event to a svg node element ?

I have the RequestHandler working correctly with divs, but i was 
  asked to set in the page a SVG that has several clickable areas.

If i do something like the following code:

```
<object id="mysvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/mysvg.svg">
   <p>Error, browser must support "SVG"</p>
</object>
```

and then add the jshelper code:

```
$this->Js->get('#mysvg-nodeID')->event('click',  $this->Js->request(
 array('action' => 'myaction', 'param01'),
 array('async' => true, 'update' => '#main_div')));
```

It doesn't seem to work. 
Can anyone share some thoughts ?

Best regards

Comment: Id of your object code & one used in js helper seems to be different. Kindly check.

Comment: Thanks on the feedback Rikesh. but i'm refering to a Id of a specific node in the SVG and not the whole object. Fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/ZWK2U/

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case some else also needs this.

There's probably a better solution, please share if you find one :)

Anyway, this one serves it's purpose. As i din't find a way to get 
 the event associated to the svg node i added javascript for that part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var a = document.getElementById("mysvg");

        //it's important to add an load event listener to the object, as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
        a.addEventListener("load",function(){
            var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM 
            var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("mysvg-nodeID"); //get the inner element by id
            delta.addEventListener("mousedown",
              function(){
                <?php 
                  echo $this->Js->request(array('action' => 'myaction', 'param01'),array('async' => true, 'update' => '#main_div')); 
                ?>
              },false);    //add behaviour
</script>
```